# Change argument in the apache logs as it comes in through mod_perl?

Tags: mod-perl

We have impressions coming in with arguments, say user=ryan&size=1234 . Is there a way that I can change those arguments directly in the log file before they are written?  We're currently using the notes() method to add argumnets but I need to change the user argument to user=ryantest before it's written. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestRec.html#C_args_  allows you to set the querystring so you can replace anything and then set the new string.